# Segmentation fault when traversing array in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote this little function in c:

```
void initializeArray(char arr[ROWS][COLS]){
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<COLS; i++){
        for (j=0; j<ROWS; j++){
            arr[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: ROWS and COLS are defined in a header file

When I call it i keep getting a segmentation fault. If I traverse the array using
a pointer its okay, any ideas why?

p.s.
The array being passed was defined outside a function so there's no link problems.

Comment: What is ROWS and COLS set to ? How big is your array ?

Comment: Marcelo that was actually the problem!

Comment: We need to see the call and the declaration of whatever you're passing.  And note that the `COLS` dimension on the parameter declaration doesn't mean anything; the parameter is really a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @yotamoo: My mistake. The pointer arithmetic is different for the first and second indices, so yes, it does explain the segfault.

Comment: @Marcelo: +1 comment for acknowledging the mistake.

Comment: The segfault only occurs if COLS > ROWS, correct?

Answer (score 10):

In your function declaration you've got `ROWS` as the size of the first dimension, and `COLS` as the size of the second dimension; but in your function body, you're looping `COLS` times over the first dimension, and `ROWS` times over the second. Depending on whether the array declaration matches the function declaration or the "implied declaration" in the code, that may be a problem.

Comment: How would the array declaration effect this?

Answer (score 6):

In the function declaration use have `char arr[ROWS][COLS]` and in your loop you use `arr` as `arr[i][j]`, where `i` is used to loop till `COLS` and `j` is used to loop till `ROWS`.

Your `COLS` and `ROWS` are swapped between both situations.

Comment: I gave you +1, but it seems you could phrase this a little better, maybe illustrate with a code example. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I slightly reformulated my answer, hopefully it is better phrased now. Except this being odd (hence my answer that they were swapped), I cannot come up with an idea why this would result in an segmentation fault. The fact the the OP comments that this has fixed the problem is even more peculiar...

Comment: Because if his indexes are wrong, he will access an invalid index.

Comment: Yes, after reading Marcelos answer I understood and thought that I have have known that myself on beforehand!

Comment: That's what I was trying to get you to demonstrate with a code example :)

Comment: Too bad my brain got stuck, now Marcelo earns the accepted answer check! Thanks for (trying) to help me out :)

Answer (score 5):

You swapped ROWS and COLS around in the loop.

The expression `arr[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(&arr[0][0] + COLS*i + j)`, and because of the swap-around, the last access becomes `*(&arr[0][0] + COLS*(COLS - 1) + (ROWS - 1))`.

If, e.g., `COLS` is 100 and `ROWS` is 50, then the last element accessed will be 100*99+49 = 9949 bytes from the start, but the array is only 5000 bytes. Flipping things the right way around, and the last access becomes 100*49+99 = 4999, which is the last byte of the array.